# Expression Engine: How do I inlude a the correct category url title in the link to an article?

Tags: expressionengine

I am working on an EE 1.7.1 site and need to display the two most recent article entries on the home page. The challenge is that I also need to link those entries back to their respective category pages to display properly.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
{exp:weblog:entries weblog="articles" limit="2"}
   <p><a href="{site_url}article/{url_title}">{title}</a></p>
{/exp:weblog:entries}
```

Here is what I would like to do so that it brings in the corresponding :

```
{exp:weblog:entries weblog="articles" limit="2"}
  {categories}
   <p><a href="{site_url}{category_url_title}/{url_title}">{title}</a></p>
  {/categories}
{/exp:weblog:entries}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work correctly. What is the right way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ExpressionEngine doesn't natively have a method of including the Category Name as a URL Segment when outputting the Permalink URI, unlike, say, WordPress.

It *can be done* of course, but will require hacking around the standard [EE URL Segments](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/general/urls.html).

If you're even the least bit curious, this was discussed in more detail on the [EE Podcast, Episide #10 Behind the Scenes at Playgrounder](http://5by5.tv/eepodcast/10-behind-the-scenes-playgrounder).

The relevant discussion between Dan Benjamin and Ryan Ireland occurs between 18:45 - 26:20, when Dan details how he developed the unique permalink structure for [Playgrounder](http://playgrounder.com/):

> **Spoiler Alert:** Playgrounder URLs are built using a last segment variable to
>  lookup the Entry URL Title, while the rest of the preceding URL is the output by
>  looping thru the entry's categories.
>
>  For example, given the following URL:
>
>  `http://playgrounder.com/stuff/learning/books/sneaky-uses-for-everyday-things`
>
>  Would translate into EE parlance as:
>
>  `/index.php/category_url_title/.../url_title`

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add dynamic="off" parameter in exp:weblog:entries tag.

Comment: That doesn't make any difference. I realize though that what is happening is that each entry displays twice. Once for the parent category and once for the child category.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to show the latest two entries and their associated categories? Such as:

> **Entry Title**
>   *Posted In: Gifts, Pets, Toys*
>
> **Some Other Entry Title**
>   *Posted In: Toys, Toddlers*

If that's what you're trying to do, the following code will output the above:

```
{exp:weblog:entries weblog="news" limit="2"}
    <p>
        <a href="{url_title_path=products/view}">{title}</a><br />

        {categories limit="1"}
            {if category_id != ""}Posted In: {/if}
        {/categories}

        {categories backspace="2"}<a href="{path=products/index}">{category_name}</a>, {/categories}
    </p>
{/exp:weblog:entries}
```

Comment: I need to be able to include the link to the category url in the link to the article. The title of the category is not important.